# Scrape historical weather data from wunderground

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to data scraping and, recently, I was trying to scrape data from wunderground.com by selenium library with python. However, I found that, sometimes, the selenium web driver cannot successfully open the webpage, I thought this issue may be somewhat related to the JavaScript the website used but not sure which parts went wrong. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Here is the example for correctly showing:
[example for correctly showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JYt8.png)

Here shows the problematic one:
[example for problematic one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHeKS.png)

My code is here, which is a very simple selenium calls

```
import requests                                                                      
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

# url for scraping
url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/ca/san-diego/KSAN/date/2021-2-1"

# define properties of selenium webdriver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 1}) #value 1 enables it , if you set to 2 it disables it  
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
option.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5) # wait for webpage loading
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page sends HTTP GET to: https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KSAN:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=20210201
The response to this call is a huge JSON that contains the data you are looking for. (below is a subset)

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1631220781880:2112944028",
    "version": "1",
    "location_id": "KSAN:9:US",
    "units": "e",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1631224381,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observations": [
    {
      "key": "KSAN",
      "class": "observation",
      "expire_time_gmt": 1612176660,
      "obs_id": "KSAN",
      "obs_name": "San Diego",
      "valid_time_gmt": 1612169460,
      "day_ind": "N",
      "temp": 59,
      "wx_icon": 27,
      "icon_extd": 2700,
      "wx_phrase": "Mostly Cloudy",
      "pressure_tend": 2,
      "pressure_desc": "Falling",
      "dewPt": 45,
      "heat_index": 59,
      "rh": 60,
      "pressure": 30.04,
      "vis": 10,
      "wc": 59,
      "wdir": null,
      "wdir_cardinal": "CALM",
      "gust": null,
      "wspd": 0,
      "max_temp": null,
      "min_temp": null,
      "precip_total": null,
      "precip_hrly": 0,
      "snow_hrly": null,
      "uv_desc": "Low",
      "feels_like": 59,
      "uv_index": 0,
      "qualifier": null,
      "qualifier_svrty": null,
      "blunt_phrase": null,
      "terse_phrase": null,
      "clds": "BKN",
      "water_temp": null,
      "primary_wave_period": null,
      "primary_wave_height": null,
      "primary_swell_period": null,
      "primary_swell_height": null,
      "primary_swell_direction": null,
      "secondary_swell_period": null,
      "secondary_swell_height": null,
      "secondary_swell_direction": null
    },
    {
      "key": "KSAN",
      "class": "observation",
      "expire_time_gmt": 1612180260,
      "obs_id": "KSAN",
      "obs_name": "San Diego",
      "valid_time_gmt": 1612173060,
      "day_ind": "N",
      "temp": 59,
      "wx_icon": 27,
      "icon_extd": 2700,
      "wx_phrase": "Mostly Cloudy",
      "pressure_tend": null,
      "pressure_desc": null,
      "dewPt": 47,
      "heat_index": 59,
      "rh": 64,
      "pressure": 30.04,
      "vis": 10,
      "wc": 59,
      "wdir": 260,
      "wdir_cardinal": "W",
      "gust": null,
      "wspd": 5,
      "max_temp": null,
      "min_temp": null,
      "precip_total": null,
      "precip_hrly": 0,
      "snow_hrly": null,
      "uv_desc": "Low",
      "feels_like": 59,
      "uv_index": 0,
      "qualifier": null,
      "qualifier_svrty": null,
      "blunt_phrase": null,
      "terse_phrase": null,
      "clds": "BKN",
      "water_temp": null,
      "primary_wave_period": null,
      "primary_wave_height": null,
      "primary_swell_period": null,
      "primary_swell_height": null,
      "primary_swell_direction": null,
      "secondary_swell_period": null,
      "secondary_swell_height": null,
      "secondary_swell_direction": null
    } ]
```

Comment: It looks really good. REALLY appreciated it, Do you know what time format it uses?   For example, "expire_time_gmt": 1612176660, in the subset you posted in the first observation cell

Comment: @BrianLiu I am glad I managed to help.  I dont know what is the time format. I think you can accept the answer.

Comment: @bladerman it's epoch time! Just find it out:)